# Change database name at runtime

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I have an application on Visual Basic 2013 , Entity Framework 6.02 , Sql server 2008R2.

I have several identical databases.

on design , I have created through wizard the connection with one of them ( For example MyDB1)  and I have configured the Entity. Now , on runtime , I want to give the users the possibility to disconnect from the database MyDB1 and to connect to another (identical) database for example MyDb2.

How can I do this through code ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

If you listed the databases via SQL it would return DB’s that may be unsuitable for your application as it would provide a list of those on the server and this may be not what you want.  I hard code the different DB options in a class and use this to setup my options. I have a class for all my DB configuration and the key parts I have listed below

```
Public Class MyDBClass
  Public Enum DBModeEnum
    Live = 0
    Training = 1
    Dev = 2
  End Enum

Public Function **GetDBString**(DBMode As DBModeEnum) As String
    If DBMode = DBModeEnum.Live Then
        Return "Server=ServerA;Database=DB1;Trusted_Connection=true;"
    ElseIf DBMode = DBModeEnum.Training Then
        Return "Server=ServerB;Database=DB1;Trusted_Connection=true;"
    Else
        Return "Server=ServerB;Database=DB2;Trusted_Connection=true;"
    End If
End Function
End Class
```

I select the DB at runtime and save it in My.Resources .CurrentDB. I call the  function GetDBString to sets the connection string, I pass My.Resources .CurrentDB to identify the database.

```
Dim connection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    connection.ConnectionString = **GetDBString**(My.Resources .CurrentDB)
    Dim cmd = connection.CreateCommand
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.CommandText = "base_Read_Case"
```

Comment: the problem is that I'm using entity framework , I've created the model step by step using wizard ,   and the connection string is saved to app.config file. I'm not creating the connection string manually during runtime because this is read from that file.